# jstree structure change use DIV Spans

Tags: jquery, jstree

Is it possible to convert ul li structure of jstree to div span structure with same indentation?

```
<div id="html1" style="width:200px; border:1px solid red;">
            <ul>
                <li>Root1
                    <ul>
                        <li>Child1</li>
                        <li>Child2</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>Root2
                    <ul>
                        <li>Child1
                            <ul>
                                <li>Child   11</li>
                                <li>Child   22</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>Child2</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

'$("#html1").jstree()'

can the same be achieved?

Comment: Why you want it so ??

Comment: I have a requirement to highlight the complete row of the tree structure which cant be achieved by `ul` `li`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
plugins: ["wholerow", "checkbox", "json_data", "ui", "themes"]
```

in your jstree rendering function. It will highlight the complete row of the tree structure. [image: Demo]

Comment: seems the jstree provide lot of features which are not captured properly in its API. @Mayank pandey thanks alot

Comment: Ya Varun, its API is not properly documented.